# Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, ionic2, cordova-plugin

Sou iniciante no desenvolvimento móvel e estava estudando o IONIC, quando fui tentar gerar o apk do projeto teste deu o seguinte erro:

> WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please
>   rename it. Running command:
>   /home/lupum/Documentos/testeionic/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /home/lupum/Documentos/testeionic
>
> add to body class: platform-android
>
> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Executei o comando:

```
sudo ionic build android
```

E antes disso:

```
sudo cordova platform add android
```

Andei procurando formas de resolver e encontrei algumas que falavam para mudar o PATH de onde encontrava o ANDROID.

executei os seguintes comandos:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/</usr/local/android-studio/>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Pois o meu android encontrasse em: `/usr/local/android-studio/`

E a plataforma do android em: `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$`

Através desse artigo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198165/failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable

O problema persiste.

Desde já agradeceria a ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá pessoal esses são os meus diretórios, como seria a forma correta de setar no path ?

Answer (score 4):

Isso parece estar errado:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/</usr/local/android-studio/>/android-sdk-linux
```

O corretor provavelmente seria isto:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-studio/android-sdk-linux
```

Se a instalação estiver na pasta de usuário, você deve usar o **caminho absoluto** (esse parece ser o seu erro), você fez:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=Android/Sdk/tools/
export PATH="$PATH:Android/Sdk/platform-tools/"
```

E depois:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=home/lupum/Android/Sdk
```

Veja que ambos você tentou usar caminhos relativos, o que as variaveis de ambiente não vão conseguir indentificar.

**Primero** essas variaveis de ambiente sempre precisam de caminhos absolutos, porque se não fizer assim elas não vão saber a o que é relativo

**Segundo**, caminhos absolutos sempre começam com `/` (Linux, Mac, Like-Unix) e se for Windows sempre começa com `C:`, `D:`, etc.

Então se você **tem certeza** que a instalação está nesta pasta `/home/lupum/Android/Sdk` o caminho digitado deve ser:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/lupum/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Note que Linux e Mac são case-senstive, ou seja se o nome da pasta tem letras todas em minuscula e você digitar uma letra em maiuscula ele não vai encontrar, então digite igual ao que está na pasta.

Comment: Quando executo os comandos acima dá esse erro:                                               WARN: ionic.project has been renamed to ionic.config.json, please rename it.
Running command: /home/lupum/Documentos/DOGIT/IONIC/ionic-bitcoins-master/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/lupum/Documentos/DOGIT/IONIC/ionic-bitcoins-master


add to body class: platform-android

Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path: /usr/local/android-studio/android-sdk-linux
Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.

Comment: Também já cheguei a atualização do Android SDK mais fala que já é de fato a versão mais nova. Então o erro é outro, também não é de permissão acredito.

Comment: @CRISLANIO Eu editei a resposta, leia novamente por favor.

Answer (score 0):

**Para configurar o ambiente de desenvolvimento Android**

Defina a variável de ambiente `ANDROID_HOME` com base na localização do Android SDK. Além disso, considere a adição `ANDROID_HOME/tools` e `ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` ao seu caminho.

**Mac OS X**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/local-de-instalacao/android-studio/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**Linux**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-studio/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**Windows**

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\local-de-instalacao\android-studio\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Para mais detalhes, veja aqui este artigo sobre [**Installing the Android Development Environment**](http://spring.io/guides/gs/android/)<sup>(en)</sup>.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54274/discussion-on-answer-by-ack-lay-error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment)